# TabItem MouseOver style disappeared with custom resource

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using `Mahapp.metro` I've created a custom header for set the font size, for doing this I've maded a statis resource in the `TabControl.Resources`, see:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
          <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Bauhaus 93" />
          <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
          <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="DimGray" />
     </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

and this is how I've applied the resource:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="Modalità notifiche" Style="{StaticResource headerStyle}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold"/>
         </TabItem.Header> 
         ...
```

Now there is a problem, the `Mahapp.metro` control style is disappeared, I've only the header with a gray font, so the user can't see if the tab clicked is selected or not, how can I recover this property? Maybe `Mahapp.metro` offers another simple solution to do this without create any static resource? I doesn't find the `TabControl` on the documentation sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `Style` yourself, you have overridden the implicit style set by MahApps. If you want to keep the implicit type, you can base your existing style on that like so:

```
<Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
      <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Bauhaus 93" />
      <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
      <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="DimGray" />
 </Style>
```

Yes, Mahaps does offer an attached property to change the header font size.
You can use `controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize` on a TabItem to get the effect.

Comment: Very interesting answer, now is very clear. I want ask you a thing if is possible, where you can find this information on the controls? On documentation of the site there isn't the TabControl. Maybe there is another doc somewhere?

Comment: I didn't find docs about controlshelper, but I discovered it from [this](http://mahapps.com/controls/textbox.html) page.